# Get separate values within Date Of Birth

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have problem to get "unique" values from this DOB input fields. Only the first row print values in last input field with class full-date. I used $this call, but in wrong way...

[JSFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/63fdud5e/)

```
<div class="info-inner">
<input data-age="adt" type="text" class="disabled-number dayter" name="dob passengers[0][birthdate]" maxlength="2" placeholder="dd" min="01" max="31">
<input data-age="adt" type="text" class="disabled-number monther" name="dob passengers[0][birthdate]" maxlength="2" placeholder="mm" min="01" max="12">
<input data-age="adt" type="text" class="disabled-number yearer" name="dob passengers[0][birthdate]" maxlength="4" placeholder="yyyy" min="1930">
<input class="full-date" data-age="adt" type="hidden" name="full-dob" data-min-date-adt="18.03.2017" data-max-date-adt="18.03.2005">
</div>
div class="info-inner">
<input data-age="adt" type="text" class="disabled-number dayter" name="dob passengers[1][birthdate]" maxlength="2" placeholder="dd" min="01" max="31">
<input data-age="adt" type="text" class="disabled-number monther" name="dob passengers[1][birthdate]" maxlength="2" placeholder="mm" min="01" max="12">
<input data-age="adt" type="text" class="disabled-number yearer" name="dob passengers[1][birthdate]" maxlength="4" placeholder="yyyy" min="1930">
<input class="full-date" data-age="adt" type="hidden" name="full-dob" data-min-date-adt="18.03.2017" data-max-date-adt="18.03.2005">
</div>
<div class="info-inner">
<input data-age="cnn" type="text" class="disabled-number dayter" name="dob passengers[2][birthdate]" maxlength="2" placeholder="dd" min="01" max="31">
<input data-age="cnn" type="text" class="disabled-number monther" name="dob passengers[2][birthdate]" maxlength="2" placeholder="mm" min="01" max="12">
<input data-age="cnn" type="text" class="disabled-number yearer" name="dob passengers[2][birthdate]" maxlength="4" placeholder="yyyy" min="1930">
<input class="full-date" data-age="cnn" type="hidden" name="full-dob" data-min-date-ch="18.03.2005" data-max-date-ch="18.03.2015">
</div>
```

I tried with this jquery:

```
$('.disabled-number').on('change', function(){
    var date = $('.dayter').val() + '.' + $('.monther').val() + '.' + $('.yearer').val();
    $(this).each(function () {
        $('.full-date').val(date);
    });
});
```

Comment: That's not how the `name` attribute works... you can't have whitespace in there. Although if (for some reason) you needed to, you could use `$("input[name*='dob']")`, which should get the input.

Comment: What exactly you want to do? Set value for each particular last row only?

Comment: You are right TricksfortheWeb. I edited js to point to disabled-number class.

Comment: Martin Jimmy Hlavňa I want to create "group" of  dd, mm, yyyy and print that date you choose in the empty last input field like this dd.mm.yyyy. Sorry if I wasn't clear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$('.disabled-number').on('change', function() {
  var container = $(this).parent();
  var date = container.children('.dayter').val() + '.' + container.children('.monther').val() + '.' + container.children('.yearer').val();
  container.children('.full-date').val(date);
});
```

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/63fdud5e/2/)